# Unable to add two time components using Dates.jl

Tags: julia, dates.jl

Hi I am unable to add two time components. Any idea why?

```
using Dates
t1 = Time(00,30,18)
t2 = Time(00,40,42)

t1 + t2
# Out > 
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::Time, ::Time)
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:560
  +(::StridedArray{var"#s832", N} where {var"#s832"<:Union{Dates.CompoundPeriod, Period}, N}, ::TimeType) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Dates/src/deprecated.jl:10
  +(::Period, ::TimeType) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Dates/src/arithmetic.jl:85
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate Julia type for your use case is [`Period`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Periods)/[`CompoundPeriod`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.CompoundPeriod). To replicate your use case:

```
julia> p1 = Minute(30) + Second(18)
30 minutes, 18 seconds

julia> p2 = Minute(40) + Second(42)
40 minutes, 42 seconds

julia> typeof.((p1, p2))
(Dates.CompoundPeriod, Dates.CompoundPeriod)

julia> p1 + p2
70 minutes, 60 seconds

julia> typeof(ans)
Dates.CompoundPeriod
```

Answer (score -3):

As stated in the comments below here is hack that I used to solve the above answer.

```
using Dates
t1 = Time(00,30,18)
t2 = Time(00,40,42)

t1.instant + t2.instant |> Time #t1.instant returns time in nanoseconds
# Out >
01:11:00
```

Comment: This looks like a hack. I don't think you are supposed to add times, it doesn't make sense. `Time` gives you a specific moment, not length of time/duration. You cannot add 00:30:18 o'clock and 00:40:42 o'clock, anymore than you can add Monday to Tuesday. You should be using Durations, not `Time`s. You can look it up in the documentation at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/

Comment: Just to add to the above, it would be `julia> t1 + Minute(40) + Second(42)
01:11:00`